# selenium gives image height and width of zero

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I am working on a image scraper using selenium (with PhantomJS) and for some reason selenium is giving me width and height of zero for some of the images that it captured...certainly it is impossible to have an image width and height of zero? how can I fix this bug? The webpage
`http://www.abacuswealth.com/`, for instance, if you look at the very bottom left corner there is a little square image that has black circle with B in the middle..this is a BCorp logo. The selenium reports this logo as having width and height of zero.

thank you

PS: Below is my code - please note that slightly more than the majority of my images being scraped by selenium have correct width and height, while the others have width and height of zero.

```
#import necessary packages
import os
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy.settings import default_settings 
from selenium import webdriver
from urlparse import urlparse
import csv    
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy import log

#set maximum DEPTH_LIMIT to 3
default_settings.DEPTH_LIMIT = 3

#set Items Fields
#the contents of the Items are 
#to be imported into the jin.csv file   
class jinItem(Item):
    SiteUrl = Field()
    htmlImagesList = Field()
    CSSImagesList = Field()
    ImagesList = Field()
    domain = Field()
    depth = Field()
    ImageIDList = Field()
    WidthHeightList = Field()
    PositionList =Field()
    AreaList=Field()
    totalNumberOfImages=Field()
    totalAreaOfImages=Field()
    ImagesFileNames = Field()
    pass

#defining CrawlSpider
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):

name = "jin"    #set CrawlSpider name to "Jin"
filename ="/Users/hyunjincho/Desktop/BCorp_Websites.csv"
filecontents = csv.reader(open(filename))
#get the list of urls that spider should start crawling from
start_urls = [''.join(f) for f in filecontents] 
#get the list of allowed domains 
allowed_domains = [''.join(f) for f in filecontents]
rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_Item')]

def parse_Item(self,response):
    Items =[]      #define empty Items basket
    self.log('A response from %s just arrived!' % response.url)
    driver=webdriver.PhantomJS('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')   #open PhantomJS...
                                                             #and attach it to the selenium driver
    driver.get(response.url) # let the selenium driver get the url and parse it
    Item = jinItem()  #make instance of class jinItem

    #all these mysterious methods(get_site_url(), get_html_images_list(), etc) are listed below...
    Item['SiteUrl'] = self.get_site_url(driver)    
    Item["htmlImagesList"]=self.get_html_images_list(driver)
    Item["CSSImagesList"]=self.get_css_images_list(driver)
    Item["ImagesList"] = self.merge_images_lists(Item["htmlImagesList"],Item["CSSImagesList"])
    Item["domain"] = self.get_domain(str(response.url))  
    Item["ImagesFileNames"]=self.get_html_images_file_name(Item["ImagesList"])     
    Item["depth"] = self.calculate_depth(Item["SiteUrl"])
    Item["ImageIDList"]= self.get_ids(Item["ImagesList"])
    Item["WidthHeightList"] = self.get_width_and_height(Item["ImagesList"])
    Item["PositionList"]= self.get_position(Item["ImagesList"])
    Item["AreaList"]= self.get_area(Item["WidthHeightList"])
    Item["totalNumberOfImages"] = self.get_total_number_of_images(Item["ImagesList"])
    Item["totalAreaOfImages"]= self.get_total_area_of_images(Item["AreaList"])  
    Items.append(Item)
    return Items

#use css selector of selenium driver to get css images
def get_css_images_list(self,driver):
    listOfImagesCSS= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("img") #returns list of images
    return listOfImagesCSS

#use selenium xpath method to get html method 
def get_html_images_list(self,driver):
    listOfimagesHTML = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//img') #returns list of images
    return listOfimagesHTML

#merge the two images list together - more specifically:
# the list that contains CSS images and the list that contains HTML images
def merge_images_lists(self, listOfImagesCSS, listOfImagesHTML):
    listOfImages = listOfImagesCSS + listOfImagesHTML
    return listOfImages

#use selenium driver get_attribute() method to get file name of the image
def get_html_images_file_name(self,listOfImages):
    filenames=range(0,len(listOfImages))
    for j in range(0,len(listOfImages)):
        filepath = listOfImages[j].get_attribute("src")
        path,filenames[j]=os.path.split(filepath)
    return filenames 

#calculate depth        
def calculate_depth(self,siteUrl):
    depth=siteUrl.count("/")-2
    return depth

#get domain(URL of main website)
def get_domain(self,url):
    parsed_uri = urlparse(url)
    domain = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
    return domain

#get the URL of sub-website    
def get_site_url(self,driver):
    url = driver.current_url
    return url

#get id of images
def get_ids(self,listOfImages): 
    ids=range(0,len(listOfImages)) 
    for j in range(0,len(listOfImages)):
        ids[j] = listOfImages[j].id #returns list of image ids
    return ids

#get width and height of images
def get_width_and_height(self,listOfImages):
    sizes=range(0,len(listOfImages))  
    for j in range(0,len(listOfImages)):
        sizes[j] = listOfImages[j].size #returns something like: 
                                        #{'width': 77, 'height': 2}
    return sizes

#get x and y offset (coordinates)
def get_position(self,listOfImages):
    position=range(0,len(listOfImages))
    for j in range(0,len(listOfImages)):
        position[j] = listOfImages[j].location #returns list of:
                                               #x and y coordinate of images 
    return position

#calculate area
#based on the width and height of images obtained through
#the get_width_and_height() method    
def get_area(self,listOfSizes):
    areas  = range(0,len(listOfSizes))
    for i in range(0,len(listOfSizes)): 
        width =listOfSizes[i]["width"]
        height = listOfSizes[i]["height"]
        areas[i] = width*height #area is a list of area of images
    return areas

#get total number of images found in a certain website
def get_total_number_of_images(self,listOfImage):
    totalNumberOfImages = len(listOfImage)
    return totalNumberOfImages

#get total area that all the images found in website takes place
def get_total_area_of_images(self,listOfArea):    
    sumOfArea = 0
    for j in range(0,len(listOfArea)):
        sumOfArea = sumOfArea+listOfArea[j]
    totalAreaOfImages = sumOfArea #sum of the area of images
    return totalAreaOfImages    

#...let the spider Crawl!!!!!!
MySpider()
```

Comment: Some code to work from would be a nice start; maybe an example of the code being scraped, too.

Comment: ok...I will add my code, thank you